# Symfony2 - Requirement to provide a value value for an argument

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, controller, routes

The following exception is being returned when trying to use the method editAction() of a custom ProfileController herited from FOSuserbundle:

> Controller "UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController::editAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$id" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

**UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController::editAction():**

```
/**
 * Edit the user
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $user = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
        ->find($id);

    if (!is_object($user) || !($user instanceof UserInterface)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */

    $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationEditFormType(), $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        // Updating the user
        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('lld_profile_show');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('info-edit', 'Your account has been updated!');
    return $this->render('UserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $user
    ));
}
```

code snippet from **admin.html.twig**:

```
<tbody>
{% for user in users %}
<tr class="">
    <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.amount }}</td>
    <td>
        {% if user.isAccountNonLocked %}
        <span class="label label-success">Enabled</span>
        {% else %}
        <span class="label label-default">Disabled</span>
        {% endif %}
    </td>

    <td>{{ user.date|date('m-d-Y H:i:s') }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.updatedAt|date('m-d-Y H:i:s') }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="{{ path('lld_user_delete', {'id': user.id}) }}" class="label label-danger">Delete</a> <a
            href="{{ path('lld_user_deactivate', {'id': user.id}) }}" class="label label-default">Disable</a> <a
            href="{{ path('lld_user_activate', {'id': user.id}) }}" class="label label-success">Enable</a> <a
            href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit', {'id':user.id}) }}" class="label label-primary">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

The specific line being used:

```
 <td><a href="{{ path('lld_user_delete', {'id': user.id}) }}" class="label label-danger">Delete</a> <a href="{{ path('lld_user_deactivate', {'id': user.id}) }}" class="label label-default">Disable</a> <a href="{{ path('lld_user_activate', {'id': user.id}) }}" class="label label-success">Enable</a> <a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit', {'id':user.id}) }}" class="label label-primary">Edit</a> </td>
```

**adminAction()**:

```
public function adminAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') || !$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') || !$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_MANUFACTURER')) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
    }

    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $users = $userManager->findUsers();

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Admin:admin.html.twig', array(
        'users' => $users
    ));
}

public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    if (!$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
    }

    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('id' => $id));

    if (null === $user) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("User with id " . $id . " doesn't exist.");
    }

    $userManager->deleteUser($user);
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('info-delete', 'The user ' . strtoupper($user->getCompanyName()) . ' has been deleted successfully!');
    
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin'));
}
```

So, I got stuck and I'm not seeing where this issue is coming from since the argument is logically being retrieved from the line where the click is being made. Obviously the right action (the custom editAction()) is being called.

Is there something I'm missing? Any suggestions please? I tried the check out similar posts but none could help me.

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is no "id" parameter for your edit route. Is there?

Comment: @Hast As you can see on the picture I've just added, there is id parameter on the route.

Comment: I mean route definition in the yml/xml file or whatever you have

Comment: I'm using the native route of FOSUserBundle. As you can see, when mouse is over the "edit" button, the route is appearing with the id parameter

Comment: Did you try to pass the Request object instead of `$id` and get the id through `$request->query->get('id')`? What happens if you do so?

Comment: No, check out my code, "$request->query->get('id')" was commented

Comment: Yes, I see that. But what IF you use it? It would be interesting to know if the request object gets passed correctly.

Comment: I tried that, it worked, but I had another issue. Let me try it again and tell you what that issue was

Comment: I think I have to leave "$request->query->get('id')" and try to fix the other issue, which is `The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`.

Comment: @PatrickBassoukissa Okay, check my answer below then. What about Form's error, please, create a new question with a full description of your issue, because it has nothing to do with the original topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your are using native FOS routing, which does not have an `id` parameter at all.

```
<route id="fos_user_profile_show" path="/" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">fos_user.profile.controller:showAction</default>
</route>
```

It's a **Profile Edit** page, which allows you to edit your own profile, so the id must be taken from a session.

If you are trying to provide some kind of CRUD functionality, you have to either switch to a ready-to-use datagrid / admin systems (e.g. [SonataUserBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle)) or write your custom routing and controller.